# How to decompress just one frame using NAudio?

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio, pcm

I am simply trying to take any or first frame from an mp3 file and then decompress it.

```
internal void Read3(string location) //take in file location
    {
        Mp3FileReader mp3 = new Mp3FileReader(location); //make a Mp3FileReader

        SECTIONA: //to jump back here when needed.

        byte[] _passedBuffer = Decompress(mp3.ReadNextFrame()); //passed the decompressed byte array here.
        int jump_size = mp3.WaveFormat.Channels *2; //just to get how many bytes to skip
        for (int i = 0; i < _passedBuffer.Length; i += jump_size)
        {
            short FinalSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(_passedBuffer, i);

            if (jump_size == 4) //converting the bytes to Int16,nothing special here.
            { 
               FinalSample = (short)(((BitConverter.ToInt16(_passedBuffer, i + 2)) + FinalSample) / 2); 
            }
            Console.Write(FinalSample+"|"); //and writing it down to Console.
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Frames are Written,continue to next frame?");
        if (Convert.ToChar(Console.Read()) == 'y') //asking to go on or not.
        { goto SECTIONA; }
    }


 private byte[] Decompress(Mp3Frame fm)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16384 * 4]; //big enough buffer size
        WaveFormat wf = new Mp3WaveFormat(fm.SampleRate, fm.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2, fm.FrameLength, fm.BitRate); //creating a new WaveFormat

        IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(wf); //passing in to AcmMp3FrameDecompressor.
        decompressor.DecompressFrame(fm, buffer, 0); //running the DecompressFrame method and then passing back the buffer.
        return buffer;

    }
```

Now the `Mp3FileReader` is reading the Frame correctly as I checked the Frame's RawData. Now I am trying to decompress that Frame and then convert its PCM data into `Int16` in that only For Loop but every `Int16` FinalSample value is returning 0.
I know that just using `Mp3FileReader.Read(Buffer,Offset,Length)` will get the job done but for all the frames so:

- how do I do it for just one frame?
- what is wrong with my code because of which I am getting all zeros?
- I know that RawData is ok, so something must be wrong with `Decompress` method, How do I setup a decompressor for mp3 file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AcmMp3FrameDecompressor` or `DmoMp3FrameDecompressor` to decompress individual MP3 frames.

You need to check the return value of `Decompress` to see how much data was returned. It's possible for the first frame not to return anything.

You should also create a single frame decompressor and use it for all frames in the MP3 file, as it retains state between calls.

Comment: I made some changes to the code, I replaced `AcmMp3FrameDecompressor` with `DmoMp3FrameDecompressor` but an exception arrived saying "Unsupported input format".

Comment: welcome to the fun world of debugging codecs! It's always a pain setting up exactly the right WaveFormat that a codec will accept. The way I would approach this is to set up an Mp3FileReader using DmoMp3FrameDecompressor and then put a breakpoint in to examine the WaveFormat it receives and make sure yours exactly matches (including any additional bytes).